# No line in Line chart , when there is only one data point {in chart js/VueChart js}

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, chart.js, vue-chartjs

Using Vue-chart-js in the below line graph I need a line when there is only one data point, i used  beginAtZero: true,, but still no luck.

dates in x axis and count in y axis with a single data point

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem.
I had made the following mistake:

```
labels: ["September, Oktober, November, Dezember"],
```

I somehow forgot to put the missing quotes

```
labels: ["September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"],
```

It would be nice to have a couple more pieces of information about your project. I could imagine, that you need more labels for the x-axis.